# geoip-database[-extra] vs geoip-database-contrib

Tags: php, geoip

While installing geoip I get the dependency conflict. I can install either geoip-database and geoip-database-extra packages, or geoip-database-contrib. I couldn't notice any difference between them, both works fine [as you see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qubsl.png)

So, is there any difference between them? Which one is preferable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geoip-database-contrib` is a superset of the data from `geoip-database` and `geoip-database-extra`.

In `geoip-database-contrib` you have both the data from `geoip-database` and from `geoip-database-extra`. The data are the same, there are no differences. There are no better sets, you simply choose the quantity of data that you want.

Comment: The question is what if any differences are there between them.

Comment: I am expanding the explanation.